# python load module get error after install

Tags: python, python-import

**Why script can't find new module after using system command to install package when the script in the running status**:

what directory structure looks like:

```
mymoduledir  
|- target_module_dir  
|- main.py
```

main.py code like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

try:
    import target_module
    print("module already exist")
    # to-do something

except ImportError:
    print("has not target_module, start install")
    os.system("cd target-module-dir && python setup.py install")
    print("install finished")

    import target_module
    # to-do something
```

**I found that:**
if python environment has no target module, my script will auto install it successfully, but I got import error. log display:

*has not target_module, start install*
*running install*
*.....*
*Finished processing dependencies for target_module*
*install finished*
*Traceback (most recent call last):*
*File ".\main.py", line 237, in* 
*import target_module*
*ImportError: No module named target_module_name*

**It means that the target module was installed successfully, but I met an importerror when I want to import it.** To prove my conclusion, I open the python shell and try import the target module, it works. When I **rerun** this script, log display:

*module already exist*

It means this script import target module successfully

**What I think is:**
script will check the python environment before launched, if I want to import an new module in running status of script, I need to let the script know the environment has updated.

**What I have try is:**
I have searched many related problem, but I haven't got an effective solution.
`For some reason, I must use python2.6 to complete my function`.And I try to use reload function, like this, but it can't work.
What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The `kafka` package does not support Python 2.6 and below. Consider updating to a recent Python and maybe server OS version.

Comment: @KlausD. This problem has no related to the module name, I have install kafka-1.3.5 to py2.6 successfully. Please see my update, thanks

Comment: If your module needs these dependencies, why are they not pulled in as part of installing your module?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Because the physical machine has no permission to connect to the internet and we have no private mirror site to use, so I only can install it via source code.

Comment: @Alvin ``pip`` also understands dependencies from source and accepts them in ``requirements.txt``. For example, ``pip install path/to/project`` will install from a local project source directory, and ``path/to/project`` should be fine in ``requirements.txt``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you very much, you mentioned me, I try to use `pip.main(['install', './target_module_dir/'])`, then import it successfully

Comment: @Alvin My point was **not** to use this inside your module, but to define your dependency for when your module is installed. You have created a non-standard, difficult to maintain "solution" to fix a problem that does not exist!

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I got your point, but I have to do this. I know how to use the standard install way, but my boss forced me to do this, because this script will be used by other department, my boss don't want they to do many operation, all they need to do is copy my code, then run it. And I think you not answer the core problem in this questions, why script can't find new module after using system command to install package when the script in the running status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pip install will work well, My Solution:

```
import pip

if __name__ == "__main__":

try:
    import target_module
    print("module already exist")
    # to-do something

except ImportError:
    print("has not target_module, start install")
    pip.main(['install', './target_module_dir/'])
    print("install finished")
    import target_module
    # to-do something
```